# Split Customer Account edit

Tags: magento2, javascript, css

i'm trying to split the customer account edit page to 2 column I tried

```
/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_edit.xml
```

this is my code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below :

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```